# Alter a date format in a view based on another date

Tags: views, datetime

In Drupal 8, I have a View formatted as a Table displaying a node type with two Date-Time fields. They are Start Date and End Date. Within the View I have them in the same column. I would like to alter how the End Date displays based on the Start Date. In particular, if the End Date is the same day as the Start date, I only want the time component displayed. I have created a Time date format for use elsewhere, that I assume will be referenced for this. In the event that the dates are different days, they need to use the default format.

I assume that one of the view hooks is what I need. But I am unsure of which one and do not know exactly what I would need to alter in the view's code.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the output using twig code:

```
{% if field_date1.striptags == field_date2.striptags %}
    {{ field_date1 }}
{% else %}
    {{ field_date1 }} - {{ field_vegdate2 }}
{% endif %}
```

Or something like this...